# getting Check-sum mismatch during data transfer between two different version of hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new with hadoop.I am transfering data between hadoop 0.20 and hadoop 2.2.0 using distcp command.
during transfer i am getting below error:

> Check-sum mismatch between
>   hftp://10.0.3.28:50070/hive/warehouse/staging_precall_cdr/operator=idea/PRECALL_CDR_Assam_OCT_JAN.csv
>   and
>   hdfs://10.0.20.118:9000/user/hive/warehouse/PRECALL_CDR_Assam_OCT_JAN.csv

I have used `-skipcrccheck` and `-Ddfs.checksum.type=CRC32` also but did not get any solution.
Solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Specify the command us are trying

Comment: hadoop distcp hftp://10.0.3.28:50070/hive/warehouse/staging_precall_cdr/operator=idea/PRECALL_CDR_Chennai_OCT_JAN.csv  hdfs://10.0.20.118:9000/user/hive/warehouse/PRECALL_CDR_Chennai_OCT_JAN.csv

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a known issue in Jira , copying data between 0.20 and 2.2.0 hadoop version https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-3054.

A workaround to this problem is to enable preserve block and check-sum in the distcp copying using -pbc.

`hadoop distcp -pbc <SRC> <DEST>`

OR

Use Skip CRC check using -skipcrccheck option

`hadoop distcp -skipcrccheck -update <SRC> <DEST>`

Comment: Still facing same problem

Comment: Can you try executing the same command in the other cluster ?

Comment: It's working if  i am using -skipcrccheck -update with distcp.But why should i use update if  transfering file first time?